The Usage of Gerunds

"Doctors say that one of the things people can do for good heart health is avoiding red meat."

"Doctors say that one of the things people can do for good heart health is avoid red meat."



I believe the first sentence is better and would be more commonly used. (Although if I'm off here, please let me know.)

However, my main question relates to the second sentence. If we can't change "avoid" to "to avoid," would it be considered grammatically incorrect, or is it okay as is?

Not sure exactly why the infinitive marker to doesn't work in your context, but it's perhaps even more obviously unwanted in, say, All you do is [to?] complain!

Would you like avoiding any better if it was one of the things people should consider for good heart health ?

Sorry for being a little unclear. It's not that I don't want to use "to," it's just that I'm working through a problem set and it asks me to choose the best option between these two sentences. I just want to check if the first one is actually best, and if the second one would be considered grammatically fine or incorrect.

Your first example is ungrammatical since gerund-participial clauses cannot function as complement to a noun. Your second example with an infinitival clause as complement is fine. Yes, "to" can be optionally added. Does that clear things up?

@BillJ: I don't understand "ungrammatical since gerund-participial clauses cannot function as complement to a noun". Consider One of the things I like [doing] is eating red meat. Assuming you don't claim that's "ungrammatical", how does it differ from the OP's example? And what about my second comment above? Does your explanation imply rejecting One of the things people should consider for good heart health is avoiding red meat (or ...giving up smoking, or whatever)? Those seem beyond reproach to me, so why would they fall under a different rule?

@FumbleFingers "One of the things I like (the most) is eat red meat." This one is ungrammatical I guess. Am I right? I guess it depends on what the verb licences. In another example it is also ungrammatical to write "One of the things people should consider for good heart health is avoid red meat" or "One of the things people should consider for good heart health is to avoid red meat"

@Man_From_India: The form of the "noun" corresponding to one of the things... depends on the specific verb in the relative clause. So One of the things I like is eat red meat is invalid, but eating and to eat work just fine there. On the other hand, One of the things I do is eat red meat is fine (where I personally find both to eat and eating "just about" tolerable, but doubtless others will have different opinions).

@FumbleFingers I second that "One of the things I do is (to) eat red meat." is correct and I think eating is not wrong either, but most people would avoid useing eating there.

Thank you for the responses. This has been helpful. So just to clarify the consensus here, because we are using 'do' in the example sentences, both sentences are possible? And if I must pick one of these sentences as 'preferable' to the other, it would actually be the second one?
